# Deleted files still taking space because I didn't empty the trash can on my school

Tags: windows, hard-drive, trash

The question simple, but I don't know what to do, I have an external HDD (1TB) and this morning I have deleted a folder with 30GB of contents, but I forgot to empty the trash.

Now I can't copy more files because I don't have space, I'm in home, and I don't know why my HDD is still having this free space:

[image]

It should be 30GB...

I have checked if I have moved the files, but I have deleted them:

[image]

Windows didn't empty the trash can because the limit is 19GB more than the data I have deleted.

**PD:** I have searched the file extensions I remember the files had, but the HDD doesn't have any file with this extension. (VDI, Virtual Box Disk)

Comment: What is your question? If you don't empty the recycle bin then you don't get the space back ...

Comment: Yes, but the recicle bin is in my computer school.

Comment: No it's not. It is on your hard drive.

Comment: Well, yes, but for some reason I can't see my $RECYCLE.BIN folder.

Comment: You need to take ownership of it if it was created on another PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probable that the operating system does not recognize that the recycle bin folder on your hard drive (the folder where elements are moved when deleted) is not empty.

You can try deleting the $RECYCLE.BIN folder in the root directory of your external hard drive. It is hidden and system so you first need to enable showing hidden and system files in the folder options (Folder Options->View->Advanced settings). If you're unable to delete the folder itself, try deleting its contents.

Comment: This was weird, because I had enabled this option and this folder even appeared, but with the CMD I solved it by doing rmdir /S $RECYCLE.BIN. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad your problem has been solved :)